# what theme to use for the AlertDialog to adjust the color automatically with day/night theme

Tags: android, themes, android-alertdialog

if the app called `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);`  it is expect to show dark theme,  and if not the app is with light theme.

Having `AlertDialog.Builder(this)`,  and would like to apply one theme so that in MODE_NIGHT  it shows the dialog with dark theme,  other wise  the dialog shows with the light theme,  something like below (but this `android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog` will causes the dialog to be always in dark theme)

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog)
```

Is there one theme for the AlertDialog? or it has to define two themes and check the mode and then to code with the theme respectively?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Define your alert dialog in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert"/>
```

In your code

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogStyle)
```

And give it a try!

Comment: we have to set this style for each dialogue or you can set the dark alert in the style.xml for the theme that is used by the activity

Answer (score 1):

add to your theme style:

```
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert</item>
```

use the dialog from appcompat

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create()
```